# How to disabled onload function on body tag by clicking anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have to load pop up only one time when index page loads. I have used same body tag in every pages.

Here is my code,

**Html File**

```
<body>
---------
------------
<a id="ac" href="about.php">About</a>
</body>
```

**Js File**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#ac").on("click", function(){

$('body').off(load);
});

loadPopUp();

});

function loadPopUp()
{

alert('xyz');
}
```

When my page went to "about.php" page, onload pop up should be disable.

Please give some suggestion or instruction regarding this.

Thanks.

Comment: can you provide a working fiddle ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a flag on your session storage, the flag will reset when you close browser,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(sessionStorage.getItem("popupflag")===null){
    loadPopUp();
    //sessionStorage.setItem("popupflag","true");
  }
});
```

if you want to disable on anchor click use this code on click event

```
$("#ac").on("click", function(){
    sessionStorage.setItem("popupflag","true");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **one** method

```
$("#ac").one("click",function(){ });
```

The **one** method will fire once, then unbind.

If you would like to ensure the function only fires once **ever**, per browser, you can use localStorage.

```
if (localStorage.getItem("SomeSiteVisitFlag") === null) {
    // Set the flag here (using the code in the event handler below) 
    // To indicate the user has visited any page of your site
    $("#ac").one("click",function(){           
        // Set the flag here to indicate that the person clicked on #ac
        localStorage.setItem("SomeSiteVisitFlag",true); 
    });
}
```

Comment: `$.one()` makes the event fire once _per page load_, not once ever.

Comment: @Sajan - that is why **ever** is bolded.  It depends on the requirements of the application.